# Vapour pressure and Boltzmann energy distribution

Tags: physical-chemistry

As theory says, there is always a certain amount of molecules in a liquid sample which have energies greater than a thresold energy and get free from intermolecular forces in liquid and produces the vapour. Theory also says that the temperature dependence of the vapor pressure is described by the following equation:
$$p = p^\circ \times \exp(-Q_\text{vap}/(RT))$$ 
But my question is how does this equation give such a specific value of vapour pressure while there are many molecules in the vapour phase having different ranges of energy, corresponding to different pressure ranges according to Boltzmann distribution law?

Comment: Note that the Boltzmann distribution is valid for each of 3 dimensions independently, as there are 3 degrees of freedom.

Comment: You put a gas in a cylinder and measure the force exerted on a piston. That's what **pressure** is about. Who cares if the molecules have different energies (which they do)? You don't measure individual molecules anyway.

Comment: There is a distribution of energy states both in the gas phase and in the liquid, while there is only one macroscopic pressure. Also, the expression you wrote is an approximation useful under a limited set of conditions.